# Every Presheaf Is Colimit of Representables

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I am working on the proof that each presheaf $F\in \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal C^{op}}$ is the colimit of $\mathbf{y}\circ \pi\colon \int_{\mathcal{C}}F\to \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal C^{op}}$ where $\int_{\mathcal{C}}F$ is the category of elements of $F$, $\pi\colon (x,C)\mapsto C$ is the natural projection and $\mathbf{y}$ is the Yoneda embedding. In the course of the proof, I showed there was an embedding of $\int_{\mathcal C}F$ into the slice category $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal C^{op}}/F$ to obtain a cocone with vertex $F$. Then using the Yoneda lemma, for any other cocone $(p_x\colon \mathbf{y}C\to P)_{(x,C)}$ under $\mathbf{y}\circ \pi$, I constructed the natural transformation $\alpha$ componentwise, using the Yoneda lemma. However, I cannot for the life of me see where I needed the arrows of $\int_{\mathcal{C}}F$ in the proof. I see how the cocone is compatible with the arrows, but can't see how they are not extraneous to the proof.

So my question boils down to: Can someone provide a counterexample of a presheaf $F$ that is not a colimit of the functor $\mathbf{y}\circ\pi$ where the domain is the discretization of the category of elements of $F$, i.e., forgetting the nontrivial arrows?

Comment: If your claim is true, then every presheaf is the _coproduct_ of representables. Try finding one that isn't. (Hint: coproducts of representables are projective...)

Comment: @ZhenLin That's a good hint. Nonprojective presheaves are not hard to come by. And going over the proof today, I noticed that the naturality condition for the unique natural transformation $F\to P$ depends on the arrows of $\int_{\mathcal C}F$ being there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a conceptual proof which goes along these lines:

1. The Yoneda Lemma entails that for any presheaf $F\colon \mathcal C^\text{op}\to \bf Set$, there is a canonical isomorphism $F\cong \int^X\hom(-,X)\times FX$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/20451/7952));
2. You can interpret the former result as "any presheaf is canonically a [weighted colimit](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weighted+colimit)";
3. $\bf Set$-weighted colimits correspond to colimits over the category of elements of the weight:
   $$
   \text{lim}^{W} F\cong \text{lim}_{(c,x)\in \text{el}(W)}(F \pi)
   $$ The proof goes by nonsense (allow me to be sloppy but evocative, it's up to you to fill the details):
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \int^{c\in \bf C}Fc\times {Wc} &\cong {\rm coeq}\Big(\coprod_{c\to c'}Fc'\times {Wc} \rightrightarrows \coprod_{c\in \bf C}Fc\times {Wc}\Big)\\
   &\cong {\rm coeq}\Big( \coprod_{c\to c'}\coprod_{x\in Wc}Fc'\rightrightarrows \coprod_{c\in\bf C}\coprod_{x\in Wc} Fc \Big)\\
   &\cong {\rm coeq}\Big( \coprod_{c\to c'\in \text{el}(W)} Fc'\rightrightarrows \coprod_{(c,x)\in \text{el}(W)} Fc \Big)\\
   &\cong \varinjlim_{(c,x)\in\text{el}(W)}(F\circ\pi)
   \end{align*}
   $$
4. Points 1+3 reads now as $F\cong \text{lim}^F\textbf{y}$, so by point 3 you get the result.

Comment: (too long for a comment, and not what you are asking for, but I like this proof too much)

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but the answer I needed...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using weighted limits.

Given a presheaf $P$, and considering $Y:C \to \hat{C}$ we have the PU :

$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{C}({colim}_P Y, X) &\cong Set^{C^{op}}(P,\hat{C}(Y-, X))\\
&\cong \hat{C}(P,X)\\
\end{align*}
$$

naturally in $X$, so that *
$${colim}_P Y  \colon= colim_{\int P} (Y \circ \pi)  \cong P$$

The arrows $f : (x \in Pc) \to (y \in Pd)$ in $\int P$, which verify $x = Pf \circ y $, translate to commutation requirement for components of the cocones of $y \circ \pi$ namely that we should have $\tilde{x} =\tilde{y} \circ f_*$ meaning we can derive all the components "below" from the "highest" component.

---

Presheaves are upward closed sets, relative to positions in $C$ (A telling picture made of nested convex sets, whose apex are labeled with objects of $C$ helps a lot to visualize). Exploding sets and viewing them from an element-wise point of view, you get the many arrows in the category of elements along with the many commutations. Every  $Q$ positioned "above" $P$ (by means of a natural transformation from $P$ to $Q$) has to commute with all of those those arrows among the category of elements in order to properly be "above" the presheaf $P$, once all elements are packed again into sets.

The smallest such $Q$ is $P$ itself, with components at $(x\in Pc)$ the natural transformation $\tilde{x} : yc \to P $

Going back to this idea of phreshaves as upward closed sets, we can think of a point $y\in Pb$ as a proof of membership at $b$ for $P$.
Taking some $f : a \to b$ in $B$, functoriality says that $Pf(y)$ is a proof of membership at $a$ for $P$ deduced from $f$ in $C$. Those proofs have to respect some transitivity built into $C$.

A diagram in $Set$ describing the category of elements as arrows from $1$, say $Pf(y) : 1 \to Pa $, $y : 1 \to Pb $ and $Pf : Pb \to Pa$ with commutation $Pf(y) = Pf . y $ gets translated by Yoneda to a diagram in $\hat{C}$ with commutation $\hat{Pf(y)} = \hat{y} . f_*$

TLDR : *functoriality* of a presheaf $P$, after "exploding" each sets $Pa$ to its ingredients, creates arrow in the category of elements. After their translation by Yoneda to $\hat{C}$, this creates commutation requirements for the cocones considered.